# ios: How do I add a new UDID to provisioning profile without a tethered device?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, provisioning-profile, udid

I know how to add from the web portal, but this particular provisioning profile is marked as "Managed by Xcode", therefore, I need to either stop managing from xcode or add a UDID into the profile from Xcode.

I cannot find any way to "stop managing" in Xcode.

In Xcode, I know how to add the device by tethering to my laptop and refreshing, but I don't see any option to add a UDID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the phone to your mac and open XCode. Then click under Window->Organizer under Devices you must see your connected phone. There is an Button named "use for Development". Click this and after a few seconds the UDID must be in your team profile and you can install the app.

IMO you cant add devices to your team-provisioning-profile without connected to your mac, if this profile is managed by xcode. Alternative make an ad-hoc-provisioning-profile.

Hope that helps?

Comment: But that requires having the device local to tether.  I am looking to add the UDID without having the device in hand.

Comment: @mobibob Why is this question marked as accepted? It does not provide a solution and instead it answers the question for which you said you already know how to do it.

Comment: kolubild's answer is the correct one, which says that added udids are automatically added to all xcode-managed profiles.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what worked (multiple times now) ...

- (Web) Login to Apple Developer > Member Center > iOS Provisioning > Add Devices
- Add UDID with a meaningful name
- Create a Provisioning Profile that includes all of your registered devices
- (Xcode) Go back to the Organizer
- Select the Provisioning Profiles section and select the specific profile
- Check the box "Automatic Device Provisioning"
- Press the Refresh button

Voila!

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 and I can't find any Provisioning Profiles in the Organizer. Can you add screenshots or does my version not support this feature anymore?

Comment: I presume that the feature "Automatic Device Provisioning" is now always on, as kolufild's answer implies. I've tested this and it is as described by kolufild. This has probably changed over the time.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply add the device's UDID to the developer portal, it will be automatically be added to ALL provisioning profiles. You can confirm this by downloading the profile and inspecting it (in plain text editor).

Comment: I have tried what looking at profile in editor, but it does not included my newly added UDID. Did i miss something?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing it, but I know it's worked before. Is there like a waiting time or do you have to force Xcode to manually update or something? I tried clicking the Refresh button in Preferences->Agent->Profiles, but it didn't work.

Comment: @phreakhead In XCode 7.2.1 I did not need to update XCode manually. I made the change in the web portal, then went to the Organizer --> Export --> "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" --> Choose a team --> "Export one app for all compatible devices" --> **this** window shows the provisioning profile that will be used to sign the app. Click the little circular arrow icon to the right of the name to open the file location in Finder. If you open that `.mobileprovision` file in a text editor you'll see a section called `ProvisionedDevices` that contains the UDIDs. The one you just added should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/edit

- Click **All**

[image]

- Pick profile

[image]

- Click edit
- Select missing device

[image]

- Click generate
- Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts
- Select your account and click View Details

[image]

- Click Download All

Comment: Hi Dawid - do you know if I can use this method to distribute my app on another platform like Diawi?