# Adding an unattached UDID to existing project in XCode

Tags: xcode, provisioning, udid

Sorry, I'm sure this question is quite basic, but from what I've read I'm doing it correctly and still not having any luck.

I have a project in XCode.  It compiles correctly and I can install it ad-hoc on all the devices that were originally part of the provisioning profile I created when I first started the project.

I now have another UDID that I need to add so they can test.  They live on the other side of the country, so I can't attach the device and add it through XCode.

So from my understanding, these are the steps I have taken:

1. Over at developer.apple.com, add the UDID to the device list.
2. Update the provisioning profile on the developer website to include the added UDID.
3. In XCode, open organizer, select provisioning profile and hit refresh.
4. Recompile.

Am I missing a step in there?  It recompiles fine but apparently won't install on the added device.

EDIT:  I found [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097917/ios-how-do-i-add-a-new-udid-to-provisioning-profile-without-a-tethered-device?rq=1), which sounds like what I want, but I can't find the checkbox for "Automatic Device Provisioning".  Where is that located?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "Automatic Device Provisioning" checkbox has been removed from later Xcode versions, check this question: [The  Automatic Device Provisioning options have gone since upgrading to Xcode 4.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880021/the-automatic-device-provisioning-options-have-gone-since-upgrading-to-xcode-4). 
The steps you listed seem good. You could check if the new profile has been effectively inserted into the ipa file: 
 - rename the .ipa in .zip;
 - navigate into Payload and then contents of the .app package; 
 - open the embedded.mobileprovision file with a text editor; 
 - search for the new UDID string inside the file.

Comment: Thanks.  That definitely helps with the confirmation of my problem.  The UDID isn't there.  I guess I just go about recreating the whole setup.  Lame.

Comment: Check the profile that you've downloaded from Apple. It the UDID is there, the problem is with Xcode. Reassign the profile in Build Settings. If it doesn't still work, manually edit the Xcode project file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291463/xcode-wont-recognize-my-new-provisioning-profile