# Deploying a React Native App for iOS without App Store

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, deployment

I am creating an app for iPad on React Native. I am working on a macbook.

I want to test the app on a physical iPad with a deployed production build of the app.

I don't seem to understand how am I supossed to do that. I'm finding a lot of info on how to deploy to the App Store, but that's not what I need.

I used to use expo for Android and build an APK and just install it on a physical device, now I want to do something similar.

This time I'm not using Expo, just react-native-cli and XCode. I tried the app on a simulator and it works, but now I want to send it to a different person so he can test it on a physical device and not on debug mode, but on an actual production build of the app.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your ***best*** option for testing is to build for release, upload to App Store, and make the build available for [Test Flight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [www.diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com) for that.

First, you'll want add any device's UDID that you want the app installed on to your provisioning profile in your app.
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9267942/2329618) out to add a UDID

Then to create an .ipa of your app, follow along in [this](https://docs.testfairy.com/iOS_SDK/Exporting_Ad_Hoc_IPA.html) link up until "Installing Your App on Test Devices Using Xcode".

Once you have your .ipa, upload that to https://www.diawi.com/
Diawi will return to you a link that you can send out to user's who's UDID you've added to the provisioning profile.